# Why am i getting weakly-referenced-object-no-longer-exists-using-python-and-mysql

Tags: python, weak-references

i am trying to run this code but am getting weak refrence error at line 6

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
con=mysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root')
cursor=con.cursor()
cursor.execute('Create database if not exists shivam')
con=mysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',database='shivam')
cursor.execute('use shivam')
cursor.execute('slect * from item') #this is a table in my database
data=cursor.fetchall()
print(data)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: slight typo in one line, 'slect * from item' should be 'select * from item'

Comment: Thanks didn't saw that.